# What does component being zero in particular dimension mean?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

I have asked a question on stack physics , basically asking why is it so that every $4\times 1$ matrix can't be written as tensor product of two $2\times1$ matrices ? (for more detail : [4-D column as tensor of two 2-D column vectors](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/173667/can-all-4-d-column-matrices-be-given-as-tensor-prodcut-of-2-d-column-matrices) ). But it led me to a stupid basic question. If I have a $4$-dimensional system with each component along a dimension being a complex number ( just for generality ) say one represented by
$$ A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1  \\
0  \\
0  \\
1  \end{array} \right)$$ 
Now its second and third entries are zeros. So it just basically has components 1 that so along first and fourth dimension. So it can be represented by just a $2$-dimensional column matrix. So why is it so that when  zero entries are there  ( meaning component is zero along that dimension ) still  the matrix $A$ is a four dimensional column matrix ? Basically when a component along say a  dimension is $0$ then why just writing $0$ in the corresponding vector/column matrix increases the dimension by 1 ? Is it just representation ? I know this seems a stupid question but is troubling me.

Comment: $A$ is an vector in a $4$-dimensional space ($\mathbb C^4$). $A$ just happens to have two of its entries $0$.  It is also belongs to linear subspaces of that space with dimensions $1$, $2$ and $3$.  Dimension is a property of the space, not of the particular vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have entry $0$ somewhere is not a vacuous statement for a matrix... It says that on that *direction* the vector has $0$ projection...

Imagine, if in a list of questions we would completely disregard the answers that are $0$... Say someone asks you if you are single or not.., does the $0$ answer make you insignificant? Or maybe you want people to know that you have visited the Carribean $0$ times, so they can finally join you there for the summer ;)

Answer (score 0):

If I have interpreted your question correctly, I think I can help.

Think of it like this. Pretend you drew dot on a 2d piece of paper. I can unambiguously describe the position of that dot with only two numbers - for example, the distance from the left and the distance from the top of the paper.
This would mean that the position of the dot on a 2d plane (like a piece of paper) is a member of $R^2$.

Of course, we could repeat this for 3d space - if so you'd need three coordinates to find an objects position, say the distance from two perpendicular walls (x and y), and a distance from the floor(z).

However, imagine a dot drawn on the floor somewhere, since it's distance from the floor plane (the xy plane) is zero you could describe it's position in 3d space as (let P be it's position):

$$ \vec P = \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$$

This just means that the dot is on the floor, but it CAN move away from the floor. Unlike a dot on your piece of paper which can not move off of the paper.

So analogously, in 4D space, you're defining the distance of a point from a 'hyperplane' which is just the 4d analogue of a sheet of paper (you don't need to be able to picture it). This time, to uniquely specify a point, we'd need four numbers, and when one of them is zero; it just means that the point lies on some origin plane.